# Getting a list of references using cscope and python

Tags: python, string, list, subprocess, cscope

I am writing a Python script to edit a large C project.  In this script I am using the subprocess module to call cscope's line oriented interface.  This is an example of what I have been doing...

```
func_name = 'main'
p = subprocess.Popen(['cscope', '-d', '-L', '-0', func_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
```

This works great for finding all the references to a function.  The problem I am having is that output is just a long string of all the references.  Is there a way to call this so it returns a list instead of one string?  The string it returns is very hard to parse since there is no real pattern to it.

Comment: Can you add an example of the output, please?

Comment: I figured it out...instead of using p.communicate() I used...
    for line in p.stdout:
        ref_list.append(line)
This gave me a list of each line like I needed